# A quick question about Keras Embedding layer

Tags: keras-layer

I have a quick question about the parameters of the Keras Embedding layer.

The `input_dim` of the Embedding layer is `vocab_len`, which is calculated as:

```
vocab_len = len(word_to_index) + 1
```

Why we need to add 1 here please?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Embedding Layer expects an input_dim that should be the total length of the vocabulary. Because lists are zero indexed you need to add the 1

From the Keras [Documentation](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/):

> input_dim: int > 0. Size of the vocabulary, i.e. maximum integer index
>   + 1.